# ^32 limitation and modulo methods

Tags: java

In Java, Integers must be between 2^31 - 1 through -2^31

so if int x = 2 * 1500000000

The logical answer will be 300000000 but because it has a limit on its value, it is thus brought forward and using 2^32 mod 3000000000 it will be -1294967296 but because it is brought forward the number will become negative because the positive field is overflown. Am i right to say that this is true?

Also, I have search and read up on the modulation part, for e.g. in a clock 
 15 mod 12 == 3 because it is the remainder of the division however it is good as an example for a clock because 12 is a constant here.

So is 2^32 is the constant of all modulation computation of integers for overflow?

Comment: Yo're not right when you say "2^32 mod 2147483648 and the result is 0 but it should be -2147483648" because `k*value MOD -value == 0` is true (where `k` and `value` are integers).

Comment: All your calculus are wrong lol. [Go back to Wikipedia!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you should grab a book that talks about binary number and overflow. Overflow/underflow is the extra most significant bit got removed (33th bit for 32-bit signed int)

Comment: In 32-bit arithmetic, 2 raised to the 32nd power is zero.

Comment: You should also read up on [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) your assumptions about where negative numbers lie is incorrect. (If it helps, think about three-digit decimal representation. -1 would be "999" since it's the three-digit number that, when you add 1 to it in three-digit decimal arithmetic, you get 0. -2 would be "998" since if you add "002" to it using three-digit decimal arithmetic, you get 0.)

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I am just starting to learn, it will be better if you could explain it more. This whole question is just an assumption and thus i am not surprised that is it completely wrong. Like for e.g. how the computer will interpret int x = 2 * 1500000000. Thanks

Comment: All `int` values are mod 2^32 not 2^31

Answer (score 5):

I am going to use 8-bit integers for simplicity.

In binary, 8 bit ranges from `00000000b` to `11111111b`.

```
00000000b = 0d
11111111b = 255d
```

So how do computer add signs to an integer? It's [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

For unsigned integer, we convert `11111111b` from binary to denary by this way:

```
  11111111b
= 1*2^7 + 1*2^6 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
= 1*128 + 1*64  + 1*32  + 1*16  + 1*8   + 1*4   + 1*2   + 1*1
= 255d
```

So how about signed integer `11111111b`? Here is a simple way:

```
  v----------(sign flag 1=negative)
  11111111b
= 1*(-2^7) + 1*2^6 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^4 + 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^0
= 1*(-128) + 1*64  + 1*32  + 1*16  + 1*8   + 1*4   + 1*2   + 1*1
= -1d
```

In general, the most significant bit of a signed number is the sign flag.

To convert negative denary number to two's complement:

```
 -18d
 ========
 without sign     0001 0010
 one's complement 1110 1101 (inverted)
*two's complement 1110 1110 (one's complement + 1)
```

The range of a 8-bit signed integer is from `-2^7` to `2^7-1`.

Now what is overflow? Let's see:

```
  01111111b
= 127d

  01111111b + 1
= 10000000b
= 1*(-2^7) + 0*2^6 + 0*2^5 + 0*2^4 + 0*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 0*2^0
= 1*(-128) + 0*64  + 0*32  + 0*16  + 0*8   + 0*4   + 0*2   + 0*1
= -128d

  127d + 1d
  =========
  0111 1111 (127d)  +
 +0000 0001 (1d)    +
 ----------
  1000 0000 (-128d) - (overflow)
```

So if we add 1 to the largest 8-bit signed integer, the result is the smallest 8-bit signed integer. +ve + +ve -> -ve is an overflow error.

How about subtractions? 45-16? (+ve + -ve -> +ve)

```
  45d - 16d
  =========
  0010 1101 (45d)   +
 +1111 0000 (-16d)  -
 ----------
1 0001 1101 (29d)   +
^---------------------(discard)
```

How about 45-64? (+ve + -ve -> -ve)

```
  45d - 64d
  =========
  0010 1101 (45d)   +
 +1100 0000 (-64d)  -
 ----------
  1110 1101 (-19d)  -
```

How about -64-64? (-ve + -ve -> -ve)

```
  -64d - 65d
  =========
  1100 0000 (-64d)  -
 +1100 0000 (-64d)  -
 ----------
1 1000 0000 (-128d) +
^---------------------(discard)
```

How about -64-65?

```
  -64d - 65d
  =========
  1100 0000 (-64d)  -
 +1011 1111 (-65d)  -
 ----------
1 0111 1111 (127d)  + (underflow)
^---------------------(discard)
```

So -ve + -ve -> +ve is an underflow error.

The situation is similar for 32-bit integers, just more bits available.

For your question `2*1500000000`, if we treat them as 32-bit unsigned integer, the result is `3000000000` and its binary representation is:

```
  1011 0010 1101 0000 0101 1110 0000 0000
= 1*2^31 + 0*2^30 + ...
= 1*2147483648 + 0*1073741824 + ...
= 3000000000d
```

But if we treat it as a 32-bit signed integer:

```
  v------(Let's recall this is the sign flag)
  1011 0010 1101 0000 0101 1110 0000 0000
= 1*(-2^31) + 0*2^30 + ...
= 1*(-2147483648) + 0*1073741824 + ...
= -1294967296d
```

---

**ADDED:** Overflow of unsigned integer

The overflow of unsigned integer is quite similar:

```
  11111111b
= 255d

  11111111b + 1
= 00000000b
= 0d

  255d + 1d
  =========
  1111 1111 (255d)  +
 +0000 0001 (1d)    +
 ----------
1 0000 0000 (0d)    - (overflow)
^---------------------(discard)
```

That's why for 32-bit unsigned integers it is always `mod 2^32`.

And BTW, this is not only for Java, but for most programming languages like C/C++. Some other programming languages may automatically handle overflow and change type to a higher precision or to floating point, like PHP/JavaScript.

Comment: WoW... Thanks! Thats alot of effort on your part! Not crazy at all and am really grateful for the examples. Will definitely save this up to prepare for school.

Comment: @AntonYeo well, I've added some information and fixed some typos, if you think my answer is acceptable, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be modding by 2^32, not 2^31, and then you should be taking into account the signed arithmetic: numbers higher than 2^31 get 2^32 subtracted from them.

Anyway, `2 * 1500000000 = 3000000000` is less than 2^32, but greater than 2^31, so it gets 2^32 subtracted to get -1294967296.

Comment: So the answer is just by subtracting only? This is the whole section  in my book stating "When a mathematical operation produces a value outside of this interval (-2^31 and 2^31 - 1) the result is kept within the interval by taking its modulo 2^32 remainder. Thus, by adding 1 to 2^31 - 1, that is to say 2147483647, we leave the interval and then return to it by removing 2^32, which gives -2147483648

Am just reading a library book, I have not started school yet so if you could enlighten me on this portion it would be great since i got the whole section wrong.

Comment: Okay.  In the _unsigned_ case, you always _just_ mod by 2^32.  Then to turn an unsigned value into a signed value, subtract 2^32 if it's at least 2^31.  To turn a signed value into unsigned, add 2^32 if it's negative.  It may be clearest if you convert the value to unsigned, mod by 2^32, then convert it back to signed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it made a lot of sense now, Will study and work at it again.